# HTML Bootstrap form <a> element not appearing as btn-secondary

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In the example below the `button` element is shown as `btn-secondary` but the `a` element isn't, as opposed to [this](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#active-state) example, where the `btn-secondary` class is assigned to an `a` element and shown to have the right effect. I want the `a` to be shown as a secondary button as well.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form-signin" method="post">

  <fieldset class="form-inline">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/register">Register</button>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/register">Register</a> 
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button">Link</a>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/register"><a href="/register">Register</a></button> will this work for you embed a tag into a button

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.btn-secondary` is not in Bootstrap 3. You need to include the Bootstrap 4 CSS instead.

Comment: Alternatively, something like `.btn-default` may be an acceptable substitute if changing the bootstrap version is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

btn-secondary doesn't exists...

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options

use default instead. Or create custom class

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2>btn-secondary class doesn't exists<h2>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">btn-primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/register">btn-secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-omg" href="/register">btn-omg (fake class to try)</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/register">btn-default</button>
<h3>On link...<h3> 
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/register">btn-primary (a)</a>
<a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/register">btn-secondary (a)</a>
<a type="button" class="btn btn-omg" href="/register">btn-omg (fake class to try) (a)</a>
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="/register">btn-default (a)</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use btn-default instead of btn-secondary , btn-secondary is not included in bootstrap v3 see this [Link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons)